# Pass detail items from a SSRS Matrix report

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

In a SSRS matrix report there is a need to click a data value and go to another report to display the details of that aggregate data.

Here is the table:

student_id course     School
1          English     A
2          Math        A
3          English     B
4          English     A

The corresponding SSRS report is as following:

School    English     Math
A           2          1
B           1          0

requirement is: click 2 (school A with English) it will go to another report as below:

Student_id  School
1             A
4             A

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a sub report that takes the required parameters. It's hard to read the question as the formatting of your data sample needs cleaning up but let's assume your subreport will take parameters aclled `pSchool` and `pSubject` with values such as 'School A' and 'English'.

Create a new report and name it (e.g. mySubReport) that accepts the required parameters (e.g. `pSchool` and `pSubject`). Add whatever you need to this report so it shows the correct results and and test it as normal. This is the report that will get called when you click on the data value.

Once this is working, got back to your original report, right-click the matrix cell you want to be able to click on and click "Textbox properties".

Click the "Action" tab and choose "Go to report".

Select the subreport you created earlier (mySubReport).
In the area below the report selection, add your parameters (e.g. `pSchool` and `pSubject`) and set the values from the dropdown list. The dropdown list will show you dataset fields that your matrix is based on.

That's it!

Now when you run the man report and lick on a value, it will pass the fields you from the cell you selected to the subreport and display the results.

If this does not help, edit you question so the structure of your data is clear and I will give a full example.

Comment: Sorry I have a hard time to format my report. My struggle is to pass a parameter because the data in a matrix is an aggregate which is just an aggregated number. As a result it losts its original details such as student_id.

Comment: edit your question and show your dataset queries, and your current report design, including any row or column group settings